# VirtualBox - Allow access to phone data is disconnecting my phone from ADB

Tags: usb, virtualbox, 18.04, android, mtp

Guest OS is ubuntu 18.04

I am using android studio on a virtual machine. The adb is disconnecting the connected phone when allowing phone data.

The problem is as follow:

1 - Connect android phone to pc phone appears in ADB devices.

2 - allow or deny access to phone data device disappears from ADB devices.

3 - Switch from MTP -> PTP -> MTP everything is solved but it is annoying to do for each time I connect a device.

Note(s):

- My Samsung phone is visible as a media device on the desktop.